# How to add filter with 2 args?

Tags: filters

I want to modify $path in the following filter. It has 1 input and 2 args.

```
function documents_template( $template = '' ) {

       $path = DOCUMENTS_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/' . $template;

  return apply_filters( 'document_template', $path, $template );
}
```

This is my function to add filter, it gets error message, how to get it right?

```
function my_template( $template = '' ){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
}
add_filter( 'document_template','my_template', 10, 2 );
```

I tried to change my return value as following, it doesn't work either:

```
return apply_filters( 'my_template', $path, $template);
```

With the belowing answers, my new filter still not working, so, maybe it's because my filter is in a class? here's the completely new code:

```
Class My_Class{
  function __construct() {
     add_filter( 'document_template', array( $this, 'my_template',10, 2 ) );
  }
 function my_template( $path, $template ){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function my_locate_template( $path, $template ){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
}
add_filter( 'documents_template','my_locate_template', 10, 2 );
```

add_filter takes 4 variables. The first and second are required. 1. name of the filter, 2. name of the function.
The third is the priority (when does the function gets fired). And the fourth is the amount of parameters. If you define the amount of arguments you also have to put them in your function. For example,

```
add_filter( 'the_filter','your_function', 10, 1 );
function your_function($var1) {
   // Do something
}
```

If the filter supports more arguments (in this case 3)

```
   add_filter( 'the_filter','your_function', 10, 3 );
    function your_function($var1, $var2, $var3) {
       // Do somthing
    }
```

Read all the codex for the information about [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)

---

```
function documents_template( $template = '' ) {

       $path = DOCUMENTS_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/' . $template;

  return apply_filters( 'document_template', $path, $template );
}

function my_template( $path, $template ){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
}
add_filter( 'document_template','my_template', 10, 2 );
```

This code works for me. Did you try this?

---

In your class change:

```
add_filter( 'document_template', array( $this, 'my_template',10, 2 ) );
```

to:

```
add_filter( 'document_template', array( $this, 'my_template'), 10, 2  );
```

Comment: add more input in my_template function doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: yes, all error is the same : call_user_func_array expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members

Comment: I edited my answer. If you remove your code the error is gone, right?

Comment: yes, I replace my code with this, still not working.

Comment: If you remove all that code you get no error? And also still the same error with this?

Comment: yes, I totally replaced my code with yours and the error message is still the same. The original filter has an input, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you show me an example? My best guess though is that there is something wrong on another place in your code. The error says that the function name doesn't exist. In the example they do exist...

Comment: I just edited my question, pasted the new code. The function name should be correct.

Comment: The problem was in your class add_filter call. Updated my answer.

Comment: OMG, it works now!!! Sorry for so much trouble.

Comment: No problem, glad that it works now :-)

Answer (score 2):

These need to match, but don't:

```
apply_filters( 'document_template', $path, $template );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'documents_template','my_template', 10, 2 );
```

`document_template` != `documents_template`

Otherwise, everything looks correct.

#### Edit

Wait, not everything looks correct. I don't think you want to add a parameter to your callback function definition. Instead, you need to define `$template` within the callback, or simply pass it back unmodified. So, replace this:

```
function my_template( $template = '' ){
```

...with this:

```
function my_template(){
```

e.g.:

```
function my_template(){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
}
add_filter( 'documents_template','my_template', 10, 2 );
```

#### Edit 2

Okay, minor mistake on my part. Try this as your callback:

```
function my_template( $path, $template ){

      $path = MY_INCLUDES_DIR . '/document/'. $template;

     return $path;
}
add_filter( 'documents_template','my_template', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake of 'document'='documents'. Now with your new function, it's still not working. error says call_user_func_array expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members

Comment: My mistake; you *do* need to add the parameters to the callback function definition. See updated answer.

Comment: The new code is not working either. I tried print_r, can see my path is correct.